# Moshi - issue serializing library class after minification

Tags: kotlin, moshi, android-r8

Recently ran into an issue with [library](https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib/blob/master/lib/src/main/kotlin/org/walletconnect/impls/FileWCSessionStore.kt#L11), which uses moshi to create runtime TypeAdapter for serialization/deserialization. The library seems to work fine with R8 disabled, but after enabling it I ran into an error message:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type org.walletconnect.impls.WCSessionStore$State. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapterFactory from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.
for class org.walletconnect.impls.WCSessionStore$State
for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.walletconnect.impls.WCSessionStore$State>
```

The solution seems to be defining `keepclass` R8 rule and it works.

But, prior to adding R8 rule, what bothers me is that if I decompile the minified binary I can see that the class in question (`WCSessionStore$State`) is not minified at all and I can clearly see that it's referenced when constructing the adapter:

```java
public final class C12848a implements WCSessionStore {


    public C12848a(File file, C10727r rVar) {
        C11124p.m43616g(file, "storageFile");
        C11124p.m43616g(rVar, "moshi");
        this.f32438c = file;
        this.f32436a = rVar.mo25906d(C10747u.m42144j(Map.class, String.class, WCSessionStore.State.class));
.
.
.
```

```java
public interface WCSessionStore {

  public State(Session$Config session$Config, Session$PeerData session$PeerData, Session$PeerData session$PeerData2, Long l, String str, List list, Long l2) {}
.
.
.
```

Also worth noting would be, that I'm running `android.enableR8.fullMode=true`

Is this expected behavior? Is the R8 rule the only way to get around this?

Comment: In general when using reflection (which serialization usually does) keep rules are needed as the R8 static analysis cannot determine the parts of the program which is accessed through reflection. The issue you run into happens https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/c5e98e5be8d6e84152d5f28b927ae077c4292d50/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/ClassJsonAdapter.kt#L160, so it seems like there is confusion between Java and Kotlin types. If you have a reproduction you can share we might be able to update https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/a05c72b29a140ee6e3350bb20518a2dee081868f/compatibility-faq.md.

Comment: hmm, the class in question should have `currentKey: String, approvedAccounts: List<String>, chainId: Long` - I'm not seeing those names here. Also, as I understand the message, it's not about the names being actually mangled or not. It's about Moshi being unable to tell if they're intact.